# Concatenate existing cells if value from another cell equals a specific value from the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
A           B
NAME        CONDITION
NAME 1      POOR
NAME 2      GOOD
NAME 3      GOOD
NAME 4      POOR
```

I want to check everything in B2 down for "POOR" and add an ASTERISK before the VALUE in A2 down, is this possible so it changes like this:

```
A           B
NAME        CONDITION
*NAME 1     POOR
NAME 2      GOOD
NAME 3      GOOD
*NAME 4     POOR
```

Comment: What changes you desired need `VBA` macro. You cannot change value in same cell by formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What changes you desired need VBA macro. You cannot change value in same cell by formula. Try below macro.

```
Sub AddStar()
Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel.Offset(, 1) = "POOR" Then
            cel = "*" & cel
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you, now I just have to run it onChange, and check if asterisk exists already.

Comment: Glad to know! If you found it helpful then please consider accepting it. Tick mark the answer so that other visitor can know it solve your problem.